# Is it possible to mount and unmout network shares through file manager?

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, filemanager

I usually mounted my NAS through fstab line

```
//192.168.0.32/hdd /media/nsa320/ cifs username=admin,password=pass,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,noauto,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

and then through command line whenever I wanted to mount or unmount it, because it's not always on.

After my last reinstall I stared playing with Gigolo, and it's easier then through the terminal, but it's harder when I want to use rsync (no mount folder), and I have problem with permissions, even when I log as an Admin.

The way I always envisioned it, but never was able to do, is to have it behave the same as a Windows partition and mount/unmount it directly through the file manager (usually with the eject icon). Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed `nautilus` then Open Nautilus, go to "File"->"Connect to Server". By giving proper arguments you can mount it in your filesystem

Comment: Then it's identical to Gigolo - when I unmout it, it disappears and I have to connect to it again, and it doesn't have  a fixed mount folder.